# Group cohomology $H^1(G,M)$ , where $G$ is finite and $M$ is finitely generated

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, group-cohomology, arithmetic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$.
Let $M$ be a finitely generated abelian group generated by $m_1,m_2,・・・,m_k$.

Let $H^1(G,M)$ be a group cohomology.

Because $nH^1(G,M)=0$ from restriction and lcorestriction argument, and $H^1(G,M)$ is finitely generated, $H^1(G,M)$ turns out to be a finite group.

But what is the maximum of the order of $M$, denoted by $\#M$ ? How can we express $\#M$ in terms of $n$ and $k$ ?

P.S. My curiosity especially lies in the case $G=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})/\Bbb{Q}$) and $M=E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))$ where $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is an elliptic curve.$H^1(Gal(L/K),E(L))\cong H^1(Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})/K),\Bbb{Z}^{rank(E/\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))}\times E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})_{torsion}))$

Comment: @Lukas Heger Thank you very much. Can you give a proof or some reference for this ?

Comment: $H^1(G,M)$ is a subquotient of $\mathrm{Map}(G,M)$, which is generated by $nk$ elements if $|G|=n$ and $M$ is generated by $k$ elements. Thus $H^1(G,M)$ is also generated by at most $nk$ elements. But it's also a $n$-torsion group, thus it has at most $n^2k$ elements.

Comment: @Lukas Heger I'm still unclear as to why$Map(G,M)$ is generated by $nk$ elements. Homomorpshim is determined by where the generator goes, but just a map is not determined only by generators, but I may have misunderstood.

Comment: As a an abelian group $\mathrm{Map}(G,M)$ is just $M^n$

Comment: More explicitly, let $m_1, \dots, m_k$ be generators for $M$. Then we can write down a list of $nk$ generators for $\mathrm{Map}(G,M)$: for any $g \in G$ and $1 \leq i \leq k$, consider the map that sends $g$ to $m_i$ and everything else to $0$. If we vary $i$ and $g$, we get a set of $nk$ generators.

Comment: The paper I’m reading claims $\#H^1(Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})/\Bbb{Q}), E(\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}))=2^{rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})-rank(E/\Bbb{Q})}$. In the case $E_{tor}=0, rank(E_D/\Bbb{Q})=10, rank(E/\Bbb{Q})=0$, order of this cohomology is more than $2^{10}=1024$. On the other hand, this cohomology is order of $H^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z},\Bbb{Z}^{10})$ is less than $2\times 10=20$ according to your observation. Where did I go wrong or is the paper wrong ?

Comment: I'm sorry, the bound should actually be $n^{nk}$, I made a silly mistake.

Comment: @Lukas Heger. Can you explain why your modified version holds ?

Comment: As I have explained, $H^1(G,M)$ is generated by at most $nk$ elements. But it's also $n$-torsion, so a $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$-module generated by at most $nk$ elements. This means that there's a surjective homomorphism $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{nk} \to H^1(G,M)$. This gives the upper bound